# Почему не применяется стиль к классу Angular 5

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angular2, angular4

Введено слово находим в тексте с помощью регулярного выражения и вкладиваем в `<span class = "match"> слово </ span>` с помощью пайпа. Спан и класс приминяеться, но стиль по этому классу не работает ((

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { PageService } from '../services/page.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'matchWord',
  pure: false
})
export class MatchWordPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    const pattern = new RegExp(this.pageService.inputSearchText , "ig");
    value = value.replace(pattern, (str) => {
      return `<span class="match">${str}</span>`;          
    });
    return value;
  }
}
```

В html :

```
<p [innerHTML]="sentence | matchWord"></p>
```

Уже и так пробовал не помогает

```
return `<span style="background-color:green;">${str}</span>`;
```

и так

```
return `<span [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'green'}">${str}</span>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно отменить инкапсуляцию в компоненте и все работает.

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...html',
  styles: ['...css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { PageService } from '../services/page.service';

@Pipe({
    name: 'matchWord',
    pure: false
})
export class MatchWordPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private pageService: PageService) { }

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        const pattern = new RegExp(this.pageService.inputSearchText , "ig");
        value = value.replace(pattern, (str) => {
            return `<style> span { background-color:green; } </style>
                <span>${str}</span>`;          
        });
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так не работает...